# How to use the encoding as per the file, while reading from spark

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, oop, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out a way to get the fileEncoding of each text file while i am reading it from the spark and use it as `.option("encoding",fileEncoding)`.
P.S - No need to have all the code in a single line.

Can some one please help me with the same?

Comment: Guessing file encodings of text files is a wicked problem. You can take it as practicably impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not really able to achieve the same in a single line, but this is how i did it in python. Followed the same approach in java as well.

> chardet_detector was the tool which made it possible.

```
import chardet.universaldetector as chardet_detector

def get_dataframe(spark, path, schema, delimiter):
    """Return a dataframe setup to read a CSV file"""
    s3_file_content = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles(path).flatMap(lambda x: x[1].splitlines()).collect()
    file_encoding = detect_file_encoding(s3_file_content)
    options = {"encoding": file_encoding}
    data_frame = spark.read.schema(schema).options(**options).csv(path).toDF(
        *[f.metadata.get("alias") for f in schema])
    data_frame.show()
    return data_frame


def detect_file_encoding(content):
    detector = chardet_detector.UniversalDetector()
    for line in content:
        detector.feed(line)
        if detector.done:
            break
    detector.close()
    return detector.result['encoding']
```

Please let me know in the comments if explanation is required. I think the code is quite self explanatory.